# Dúvida em select com group by e count?

Tags: oracle, group-by, count

Estou fazendo um `SQL` em 2 tabelas no `Oracle` e gostaria de agrupar as informações de acordo com o ***código do cargo*** e também contar quantas pessoas estão nesse cargo.

Estou usando o seguinte `SQL`:

```
select f.numemp, f.numcad, f.nomfun, f.codcar, c.titcar, count(*) from R034fun f
join R024car c
on f.codcar = c.codcar
where f.codcar in ('0001157','800739','800852') and f.sitafa <> 7 
group by f.codcar
```

Porem Recebo o seguinte erro:

> `ORA-00979: não é uma expressão GROUP BY
>   00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
>   Cause:Action:
>   Erro na linha: 1 Coluna: 8`

Alguém pode me ajudar dizendo o que está errado em meu código?

Answer (score 2):

No Oracle o "group by" tem de ser o mesmo do "select"

```
select f.numemp, f.numcad, f.nomfun, f.codcar, c.titcar, count(*) from R034fun f
join R024car c
on f.codcar = c.codcar
where f.codcar in ('0001157','800739','800852') and f.sitafa <> 7 
group by f.numemp, f.numcad, f.nomfun, f.codcar, c.titcar
```